# Finding the intersection of list in list

Tags: python, list, intersection

[image: Venn Diagram]

I know that this:

```
set.intersection(*list)
```

will output the area shaded in brown in the linked picture.

But I'm having trouble trying to get the area highlighted in pink

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but maybe you wants something like this:

```
l1 = set([1,2,3,4])
l2 = set([1,2,5])
l3 = set([0,1,3])
pink = l1 & l2 | l1 & l3 | l2 & l3
```

Comment: It should be `(l1 & l2 | l1 & l3 | l2 & l3) - set.intersection(l1, l2, l3)`. And the first part can be done programmatically using `itertools.combinations`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this generically for any number of lists, you can count how many lists contain each number.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

my_lists = [range(10), range(2, 20, 2), range(1, 25, 3)]

cntr = Counter(chain(*map(set, my_lists)))
print cntr
```

Now, if you wanted the pink region including the brown region:

```
>>> print {v for v, cnt in cntr.iteritems() if cnt >= 2}
set([1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16])
```

or if you want the pink region excluding the brown region:

```
>>> print {v for v, cnt in cntr.iteritems() if cnt >= 2}
set([1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16])
```